# Unable to import tensor flow into my python code

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, dll

I am trying to import the tensorflow model into my code but its always thowing me the dll Link error, i have tried installing various versions but none seem to work.

i have installed multiple versions of tensorflow
uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda
tried installing tensorflow using wheelfiles

> ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py",
>   line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

I expect the tensorflow to be successfully install and run on my machine

**Note : i use windows 10 OS**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be due to protobuf, try downgrading protobuf to 3.6.0 using:

```
pip install protobuf==3.6.0
```

If not try installing tensorflow using wheel file provided in the below link:

https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.12.0/py36/CPU/sse2

Hope this could solve your issue.

Comment: thanks but i have tried downgrading protobuf with no success.

Comment: did you try to install tensorflow using wheelfile?